# GraphQLError: Input Object type must define one or more fields

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I have this error

```
GraphQLError: Input Object type CreateUserInputDTO must define one or more fields.
      at SchemaValidationContext.reportError
```

I have tried some suggestions, but still doesnt work
[Input Object type `TypeName` must define one or more fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59527847/input-object-type-typename-must-define-one-or-more-fields)

I am not sure why am having this error because the other project I had works. I suspect that probably I use the latest modules ?

Here is the code

```
import {
  Field,
  InputType,
  IntersectionType,
  ObjectType,
  OmitType,
} from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { BaseDTO } from 'src/shared/dto/base.dto';

@ObjectType({ isAbstract: true })
@InputType({ isAbstract: true })
export class UserBaseDTO {
  @Field()
  public email: string;

  @Field()
  public firstName: string;

  @Field()
  public lastName: string;

  @Field({ nullable: true })
  public lastLoginTime: Date;

  @Field()
  public bio: string;

  @Field()
  public dob: Date;
}

@ObjectType()
export class UserDTO extends IntersectionType(
  UserBaseDTO,
  BaseDTO,
  ObjectType,
) {}

//the error is here, if I add properties it will work
@InputType()
export class CreateUserInputDTO extends OmitType(UserBaseDTO, [
  'lastLoginTime',
]) {}
```

this is the dependency in the package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:dev:db": "./scripts/start-db.sh",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "typeorm": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli -d src/config/ormconfigs.ts",
    "migration:create": "cross-env ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli migration:create ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:generate": "cross-env npm run typeorm -- migration:generate ./src/migrations/$npm_config_name",
    "migration:run": "npm run build && npm run typeorm -- migration:run",
    "migration:revert": "npm run typeorm -- migration:revert"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/gateway": "^2.1.1",
    "@apollo/subgraph": "^2.1.1",
    "@nestjs/apollo": "^10.1.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.11",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.11",
    "@nestjs/graphql": "^10.1.1",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.11",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^6.1.2",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.10.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^8.3.6",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.5.0",
    "ts-morph": "^16.0.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.1.3",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.11",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.14",
    "@types/jest": "^29.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "jest": "^29.0.3",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "supertest": "^6.2.4",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3",
    "yarn-upgrade-all": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PickType`, `OmitType` and `PartialType` take the fields of the base class (`UserBaseDTO` here) according to its own decorators by default. Since the base class is purely abstract, this leads to an input with no fields.

The [solution](https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/688#issuecomment-604891923) is to pass the target decorator property when mapping abstract types:

```js
@InputType()
export class CreateUserInputDTO extends OmitType(
  UserBaseDTO,
  ['lastLoginTime'] as const,  // by the way, `as const` generates better TypeScript types; has no effect on the GraphQL generated types though
  InputType                    // now this is the decorator that will be applied to `UserBaseDTO` when mapping this type
) {}
```